# usb stick not recognised by system

Tags: hardware, usb-drive

I have a Kingston USB stick that when attached to my Linux box it cannot get recognized. In `fdisk -l` I cannot see the drive. In `dmesg` it has the following:

```
[  236.538939] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  236.688591] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=5200, bcdDevice= 1.10
[  236.688597] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  236.688600] usb 2-2: Product: 2303 Boot ROM           
[  236.688602] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Phison                  
[  236.690122] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  236.690705] scsi host4: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[  237.723337] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access              2303 PRAM        1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  237.723904] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  237.731393] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

When I run:

```
root@laptop:~# fdisk /dev/sdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.33.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: No medium found
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Does it work on other machines, e.g. Windows? Does gdisk give more information?

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak Your name suggests experience, yet i read utter bs. Where do you get this information from? The stick identified and the SCSI subsstem assigned a device file. With the information given, i can't see any error. My first idea was, that it might have a gpt partitioning scheme. Maybe the OP has left out some relevant information, but so far everything seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

### Basics

Information below found on behalf of these 2 lines:

```
[  236.688600] usb 2-2: Product: 2303 Boot ROM           
[  236.688602] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Phison
```

---

### Investigation

Let me quote [flashdrive-repair.com](http://www.flashdrive-repair.com/2014/01/how-to-format-Phison-ps2251-03-ps2303-up303-Toshiba-TC58NC2303G5T-chip-controller.html), visit for complete information (spelling and formatting corrected, links removed):

> Here we will explain how to repair **Phison PS2251-03, PS2303, UP303, and Toshiba TC58NC2303G5T** USB flash drives. If you have a corrupted Phison PS2251-03 and you need its firmware to fix it, here is the solution.
>
> I gather to you all possible Phison PS2251-03 Firmware and format tools. Phison PS2251-03 Recovery tool allows you to format Phison PS2251-03, PS2303, UP303, and Toshiba TC58NC2303G5T chip controllers.
>
> First you need to use **Chip Genius software** to determine your flash information, and if your flash drive chip controller is **Phison PS2251-03**, you can use this software.

---

### Conclusion

I would normally recommend dumping this USB stick, but that would not answer the question. The answer is that your USB flash drive has **corrupted firmware and the data is gone**.

Answer (score -1):

1. Backup your data(if exist) to disk image. `dd if=/dev/sdb of=stick.img`.
2. Erase stick `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb`.
3. Try to partitioning stick via fdisk.